# Expected Single Ton Sequence -got multi item seqence for an xml column which contains namespaces

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing, xsd, for-xml-path

```
ROW 1: 

 <a:employees xmlns:a="abc.com/123" xmlns:b="xyz.net/456">
<a:emp>
<a:name>Scott</a:name>
<b:favorites>
<b:color>red</b:color>
<b:color>orange</b:color>
</b:favorites>
</a:emp>
<a:emp>
<a:name>John</a:name>
<b:favorites>
<b:color>blue</b:color>
<b:color>green</b:color>
</b:favorites>
</a:emp>
</a:employees>


   Row2:

<a:employees xmlns:a="abc.com/123" xmlns:b="xyz.net/456" xmlns:c="pqr.edu/789>  
<a:emp>
<a:name>Tiger</a:name>
<b:favorites>
<c:phone>apple</c:phone>
<c:phone>samsung</c:phone>
<b:color>purple</b:color>
<b:color>pink</b:color>
</b:favorites>
</a:emp>
<a:emp>
<a:name>peter</a:name>
<b:favorites>
<c:phone>nokia</c:phone>
<b:color>violet</b:color>
<b:color>indigo</b:color>
</b:favorites>
</a:emp>
</a:employees>
```

Above two xml documents are the rows of an xml column xml_col of table your_table.
I tried to parse the xml columns into relational data using the below query.

```
 select x.*
 from your_table y,
 XMLTable(XMLNamespaces('abc.com/123' as "a",
                   'xyz.net/456  as "b",'pqr.edu/789 as "c"),'*:employees'
 Passing y.xml_col
 Columns
 name varchar2(20) PATH '//*name',
 phone varchar2(20) PATH '//*phone',
 color varchar2(20) Path '//*:color')x
```

I am getting the below error message
"XMLTABLE in oracle - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence"

The problem is due to having multiple color and phone occurences. I want the multiple occurences to be in multiple rows. I dont mind even if the name value repeats.
Output should be similar to the below format.

```
   Name     Phone       Color
   Scott                red
   Scott                orange
   John                 blue
   John                 green
   Tiger    Apple       purple
   Tiger    samsung     pink
   peter    nokia       violet
   peter                indigo
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412515/xmltable-in-oracle-xquery-dynamic-type-mismatch-expected-singleton-sequence

Comment: I have checked the above post, but that query does not contain namespaces. The structure of the xml is also different. I am looking for a query which contains namespaces. Thanks for the response